# Data interaction firebase realtime

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following JSON:

[image: Json]

I would like to add the "qtd_lote_vendido" fields, but I am not able to access them.

```
var query = dbrealtime.ref('eventos/Bzu0eH4jTdbIQmcRuCSa/lotes');
query.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  for (var key in snapshot.val()) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(snapshot.val().key.qtd_lote_vendido); 
  }
});
```

The id is passing correctly.

```
GuR07hcFOxc1YOCqEPkL
```

But the field I need not

```
firebase.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'qtd_lote_vendido' of undefined
    at (index):46
    at firebase.js:1
    at exceptionGuard (firebase.js:1)
    at e.raise (firebase.js:1)
    at e.raiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate_ (firebase.js:1)
    at e.raiseEventsForChangedPath (firebase.js:1)
    at e.onDataUpdate_ (firebase.js:1)
    at t.onDataPush_ (firebase.js:1)
    at t.onDataMessage_ (firebase.js:1)
    at e.onDataMessage_ (firebase.js:1)
```

Comment: TL;DR ~ you want `snapshot.val()[key].qtd_lote_vendido`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the value of key, not the word key:

```
console.log(snapshot.val().key.qtd_lote_vendido);
```

becomes

```
console.log(snapshot.val()[key]qtd_lote_vendido);
```